# How to open one form after button is pressed, and also keep them in the same window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to have my code to open a new Form in the same window when the button is pressed.

I'm relatively new to this, and this is what I tried, and this is the output that I am getting.

I have been looking around and I'm completely stuck. Any ideas?

```
 private void profilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
    }
```

`System.InvalidOperationException:` Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use `Form.ShowDialog` instead.

Comment: Sorry, my code didn't add after the click command. This is what I tried. Application.Run (new profilesTab());

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void profilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      new profilesTab().Show();
 }
```